# How to set the style of polygons in openlayers 4?

Tags: openlayers

With openlayers 4, I copy one or more polygons from one layer to another, and since they do not have styles, I would like to assign them one.
I can put a style on the layer but polygons do not have export styles. That's why I try to put a style to the polygons without success.
The following code returns "TypeError: ... is not a function"

```
var Polygon= new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',//'#ffffff'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ffcc33',
            width: 4
          })
        });
        getDrawingLayer().getSource().addFeatures(select.getFeatures().getArray());//pass the polygons
         //getDrawingLayer().setStyle(Polygon)};//succes
getDrawingLayer().getSource().getFeatures().setStyle(Polygon);//try to set the style of polygons
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution :
instead of

```
color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
```

I put

```
color: [255, 255, 255, 0.5],
```

Answer (score -1):

ok I understand, because the layer is an array, I have to assign each feature from it
with

```
getDrawingLayer (). getSource (). forEachFeature (function (feature) {
feature.setStyle (Polygon);});
```

Comment: Looks like a static style. It's better to set that on the layer instead of each feature: `getDrawingLayer().setStyle(Polygon);`

Comment: hello
if I do so, the Geoportail plugin don't export any style in kml (GpPluginOl3.js)
polygons are white without stroke